# Can I make MS Word take focus when opening a second docx file via http?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, ms-word

I am adding a docx file to a folder exposed via a virtual folder in IIS, and a corresponding URL to access the file in a commercial web application we are using here (OrgPlus Enterprise).  The URL is quite simple:

```
http://IISServer/virtualfolder/documentname.docx
```

When MS Word is NOT open on my computer and I click the URL link, MS Word opens with the document from the URL, and MS Word takes focus on my computer.  This is the desired behavior.

However, if MS Word is already open with another document, the behavior is different and not desired.  After the the URL link is clicked, the MS Word icon in the taskbar (Windows 7) blinks a few times, then stays a solid blue.  MS Word does not take focus and load the document from the link unless the taskbar icon is clicked or the MS Word application window is clicked or moved.  I would like MS Word to take focus and display the document regardless if it is already open or not.

While this is trivial for savvy users, my end users are not, and I'm concerned I will get numerous support requests that the document isn't opening with this behavior.

Environment details: Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit), IE8 (8.0.7601.17514), MS Word 2013

During research I've come across the concept of Win7 preventing applications from stealing focus, so I thought maybe this behavior wasn't possible.  But when I open docx files via http from our internal sharepoint site, I can get the desired behavior no matter how many documents MS Word has open.  I can't see any difference between the URLs in sharepoint and the URL I've created in OrgPlus Enterprise.

I also found this regedit solution, but it did not work for me:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-x64-pro-window-focus-issueswhen-i-open-a/a55aec2b-ee7e-40f2-bc8b-8f4728671ca4

Any ideas to force MS Word to take focus when already open?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your environment on a test machine running Windows 7 Ultimate and by default it didn't work as expected; however, by applying the following registry patch, it works fine now. Can you try again to make sure you have made the proper modification to the registry.

You can copy and paste this in a text file with .reg extension and run it and it should make it quicker and easier than manually doing it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ForegroundLockTimeout"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: This registry update is the same as the link from my post suggests, but it hasn't worked for me, even after a couple of restarts.  Pic of my registry: http://snag.gy/9PNh1.jpg        But I will try the running your update as you suggest to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I just observed that the first time after a system restart that I open a second document, I get the desired behavior.  However, any subsequent tries before another system restart gives me the undesired behavior.  Due to system security, I'm only able to try opening that one document.  Maybe some type of cacheing issue?  I've cleared IE cache numerous times, with no change in behavior.

Comment: @user640118 I was just offering a way to make sure there was no typo :) if you followed the original post you did it correctly and your screenshot clearly shows that. As for the second thing you mentioned, application cache should not be a factor in this matter as system documents are not handled the same as web cache documents. Even though you are running it off a IIS inside IE, the document itself should not be cached, although the page and the temporary downloads to the system TEMP folder probably are. The physical file itself should be treated the same by the system each time. BRB

Comment: @user640118 I am at a loss here as to why it is not working and although I doubtful this will fix it, some of my colleagues whom I just asked about your problem suggested clearing your Prefetch folder (which I personally don't think affects this but why not try right, won't hurt anything). So open up a command prompt with administrator privileges and type `del %windir%\Prefetch` answer `YES` and then if you can restart the machine you are trying it on and give it another go and see. Good luck.

Comment: Cleared the Prefetch and restarted, but the behavior is the same as before.  Thanks for your help, I'll keep digging and hope I find something.

Comment: @user640118 I am sorry that didn't work. I have actually been digging on a solution on this and if I find something, I will put it here right away.